# AJAX Progress: Reading output from the Shell

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line

**Objective**: Make a progress bar where users can check how much of a file has been downloaded by my server.

**Scenario**:I have a PHP script that executes a python script via popen. I have done this like so:

```
$handle = popen('python last', 'r');

$read = fread($handle, 4096);

pclose($handle);
```

This python script outputs to the shell something like this:

```
[last] ZVZX-W3vo9I: Downloading video webpage
[last] ZVZX-W3vo9I: Extracting video information
[download] Destination: myvideo.flv
[download]   9.9% of 10.09M at    3.30M/s ETA 00:02
```

**Problem**:When I read in the file generated by the shell output I get all the shell output except the last line!? WHY?

Just to add, when I run the command via the shell, the shell cursor appears at the end of that line and waits till the script is done.

Thanks all

Comment: Reading through your question, I couldn't help but notice that the *problem* you have (missing line from input) has nothing to do with the question title whatsoever. You might change the title to mach your problem. Maybe "PHP: reading output from the shell" is better, as this is not AJAX related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that comes into my mind: maybe the program detects that it is not executed on a TTY and therefore does not show the last line, which probably involves ugly control characters because that line seems to update itself?

What happens when you redirect the output to a file (in the shell), or pipe it through less? If you don't see the last line there, this is likely to be the case. I don't know of another solution than to fix the source.

Comment: Yes that last line updates itself. How do i get what is being updated?

Comment: Well, as I said, it is possible that it is simply not printed when the program detects that it does not run on a tty. If that is the case, you will have to modify the program or try to find a command line option (if available) so that it does print the info, even when it is not on a tty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading until EOF?

```
$handle = popen('python last', 'r');
$read   = "";

while (!feof($handle)) {
  $read .= fread($handle, 4096);
}

pclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be your friend:

```
$handle = popen('python last 2>&1', 'r');
```

Further info can be found here: [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null)